# Unable to copy custom RDS Parameter Group across account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I'd like to copy/share RDS custom db parameter group across account, but I am unable to do that.

Is there any possibility to copy custom db parameter group to different account either using console or AWS CLI/boto3/lambda?